# Why did MR-3 and MR-4 perform a retrofire?

Tags: reentry, project-mercury, retrorockets

Mercury-Redstone 3 and 4 were suborbital spaceflights and would have re-entered anyway. Yet, the spacescraft made a retrofire burn after apogee. Was it to adjust the path to land at a specified spot in the Atlantic ocean? Or would the capsule fall too fast otherwise and heat up too much for the heat shield to be bearable? Or a mix of both?

[A similar question about the Falcon 9 first stage](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/65519/why-does-the-falcon-9-first-stage-perform-a-burn-at-60-km-altitude)

Comment: Please, ask only one question per question. Case in point: I know the answer to the F9 question, but I cannot write an answer because my answer wouldn't considered to be an answer to the whole question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Alright, I asked the Falcon 9 question seperately and linked it.

Comment: I believe it was just part of testing the capsules' systems. An orbital flight would need a retro burn, and they wanted to be sure it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found a positive statement of why, but the [MR-2 postflight report](https://tothemoon.ser.asu.edu/files/mercury/mercury_redstone_2_postlaunch_report.pdf) describes the results of *not* doing it on a suborbital flight (plus an overburn during the boost and additional delta-v due to the escape tower firing):

> This greater velocity and the lack of retrofiring (retrorockets are jettisoned in this abort mode) resulted in a range of 363 nautical miles, a maximum altitude of 136.2 nautical miles , a period of weightless flight of about 6-1/2 minutes, with a maximum re-entry acceleration of 14.6g.

[**This New Ocean**](https://ia601303.us.archive.org/32/items/thisnewoceanhist00swen/thisnewoceanhist00swen.pdf) (the official NASA history of Project Mercury) also mentions the lack of retrofire as a contributor to the overshoot of the planned landing site.

> The retrorockets jettisoned prematurely when the tower aborted, which meant that the spacecraft on reentry would not be artificially
> slowed down and therefore would gain still more downrange mileage.

The postflight report gives this plot of the planned vs. actual trajectory, but I am not sure how much of the difference is due to the overburn vs. the lack of retrofire.

[image]

Also planned vs. actual acceleration:

[image]

It is also likely that there was a desire to test out the retrofire system before orbital flight - **This New Ocean** describes the program management's fear of having an astronaut stuck in orbit and their brainstorming of alternate deorbit methods including a kind of "drag balloon".